# How to upload a large file on Google drive using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to upload a large file on google drive but I am getting a warning that my app is not verified by google.I am using pydrive.Give me a solution using pydrive or using another way.

Answer (score 0):

use the google cloud platform

have not used it much but pretty sure it works

Answer (score 0):

Using that module of python you can upload large files on google drive.

```sh
pip install gdrive-python
```

Then you have to allow the script to upload files on your Google account with this command and follow the instructions:

```sh
python -m drive about
```

Finally, upload the file:

```py
form gdrive import GDrive

drive = GDrive()
drive.upload('path/to/file')
```

You can also use multithreading to upload files:

```py
form gdrive import GDrive

drive = GDrive()
thread = drive.upload('path/to/file', thread=True)
tread.start()
# do your stuff
tread.join()
```

More info on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/vittoriopippi/gdrive-python